# Как работать с полем Date в Android базе "SQLite"

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

Существует ли поле типа Date/Time или аналог в Android базе SQLite? 
Как тогда указать при создании таблицы это поле

`Create table 'my_table'(date ?????)`

и как производить запросы к этому полю?

Answer (score 3):

В SQLite нет типа Date. Храните как int или текстом
http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

SQLite не имеет специального типа для даты-времени, но есть функции работы с датой и временем. Причём тип данных не фиксируется, и если поле объявлено как `INT`, `DATETIME('now')` туда запишет строку. Поэтому важно писать в БД дату всегда в каком-то одном формате и часовом поясе (лучше UTC). При записи лучше прогонять всё через функцию `JULIANDAY()` или `DATETIME()` (отбрасывает доли секунд и не соответствует ISO за то сразу видно какая дата в `SELECT *`), **но только всегда через одну и ту же**.

Объявлять колонку можете как `DATE` или `DATETIME` -- это роли не играет, `JULIANDAY()` запишет `REAL`, а `DATETIME()` -- `TEXT`.

Форма `JULIANDAY` удобна тем, что можете производить арифметические операции, учитывая, что единицы -- это дни, 1./24 -- часы и т.д.

Ещё можно использовать представление в секундах от начала Unix-эпохи, но мне кажется это менее удобным.